# Recommended way to store strings for a multi-language PHP application

Tags: php, internationalization, multilingual, recommendation-engine

Normally I associate strings to keywords that describe them, and then store them in a database table with a structure of `id int, id varchar(16), language char(2), string varchar`. Then I make a PHP wrapper function to fetch each string depending on the visitor’s current language.

I have been told (and read somewhere I think) to use PHP’s built in methods to handle internationalization. But I have not found any really “convincent” information about why it should be more appropriate than my database way to do it.

What is the most appropriate method to handle internationalized websites strings and why? is there one that I should always prefer for its better performance? If there is one with a better performance then I will switch to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your objectives are. If you need your translations to be updated on-line by website users, then your database approach is ok. However, if translations are to be provided by professional translators, then it's better to decouple the translation from the web site. Using something like gettext is a better idea in this case - you will be able to send out .po files for translation, then integrate it back into your web site.

Think about the whole process, managing translators, managing changes, etc.

Comment: +1  Gettext is great, it is fast and efficient and should require less overhead than constantly hitting the database for translation strings.  If you can cache your translations somewhere so you don't have to hit the database all the time then that is good too, you can also cache gettext translations if you have a more efficient caching system.

Comment: @drew010 please name me a couple of caching systems.

Comment: I use [memcached](http://www.memcached.org/) in a lot of projects.  That caches data in memory for very fast access.  PHP has extensions to interact directly with a memcached server.  If done properly, you could even cache your translations as a serialized array or object in a file.  Depending on how busy your site is, you will need to pay close attention to updating translations because you could have two processes that want to update the cache with different translations and one ends up overwriting the other.  Therefore memcached may be a better option.  APC and xcache are others to look at.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to skin a cat. I think you've been given this advice because PHP uses the client settings to get the default language (although, you're probably using a similar method). Either way, multiple strings have to be stored. If you prefer the db save those strings, then that works. If you're not seeing any performance issues, then go with it. No need to change what you're comfortable with.

Comment: Then I add to the question... will one have better performance?

Answer (score 0):

Gettext seems to normally depend on each proccess’ locale settings, and they depend on system installed locales too. For Web Applications consider using your own Database implementation along with some caching methods already pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I want to ask, were you upvoting my answers and questions this morning?