# Is it a good idea to store all php/html strings in one file?

Tags: php, string, multilingual

I'm currently working on a school project that requires building a php application. I've started off by writing most of the functions the application will be needing however i'm not comfortable with the fact that i have to go through all my code to find and change the strings that get printed to the user, being that i make very frequent changes.
I was wondering if there was a better approach? Kind of the way android handles multi-language applications by having all the strings in one file. I understand that the main reason for this is for translation and since my system only has one language, i don't really require this. 
So would it be wrong (I.e: it would somehow bring to further complications) to use the same approach?

I was thinking of a class with a bunch of static variables which could be referenced from the other functions.

What about what [Mario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622780/recommended-way-to-store-strings-for-a-multi-language-php-application) is suggesting? I understand that this is not my case since i don't need multi-language support but being that the case would a db still be a bad idea?
Thanks

Comment: You should separate your files as much as necessary. Certainly separate PHP code which contains business logic from HTML code which contains view templates. Continue further and separate everything nicely into an MVC structure. All user-visible strings should end up in the V part, nothing from M or C should directly end up on the user's screen. Then the whole thing becomes a lot simpler.

Comment: There are plenty of PHP solutions that do exactly as you describe, such as the [Symfony translation module](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html), or the venerable [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html) system, used through a PHP extension by systems like WordPress. Gettext includes features like compilable language files that have handy editing tools  specifically designed so that human translators can easily translate your strings without editing a single line of code, but can be more overhead to maintain than simpler systems.

Comment: Also, even if you only have the one language, it can sometimes be helpful to have all your strings in one translation file. I've found this useful on two projects recently: one where a rebranding exercise meant changing every occurrence of one company name to another, where we only needed to change a single file to make it all work, and another where the original programmer was just really bad at spelling, and it was much easier to check the translation file than if the strings had been scattered across the system...

Answer (score 0):

For translations, it depend on size of file, if it will be small one - sure. Can be all in one file. But if project will grow. Better is group strings and put in different files. 
It will help only to find and edit it. Doesn’t matter for speed or error handling.

Different thing is separate php & html. But this also depend on project. In some it's OK. I think best is to have separate template global layout from php generated only output. In PHP you will any way put some html tags.

Functions, best - should be group in class. One class - one file.